# (modified) jQuery slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have a jQuery slideshow code that works fine with the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slideshowImages">
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="slideshowNav">
        <span id="slideshowLeft"><a href="#"><img src="images/slideshowLeft.png" alt="&gt;" /></a></span>
        <span id="slideshowRight"><a href="#"><img src="images/slideshowRight.png" alt="&lt;" /></a></span>
    </div><!-- /#slideshowNav -->
</div><!-- /#slideshow -->
```

Though now I wanted to modify it so that it'll work with the same structure, but instead of just plain images, the images are now links. That is, the "meat" of the slideshow markup is now:

```
<a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

The jQuery code that makes the slideshow work is a bit lengthy, so I figured I'll just post the necessary stuff. It works on this principle:

```
jQuery('#slideshowImages img:first').addClass('active');
jQuery('#slideshowImages img:last').addClass('lastImg');

var $active = jQuery('#slideshowImages img.active');

var $previous = $active.prev().length ? $active.prev(): jQuery('#slideshowImages img.lastImg');

    $active.animate({opacity:0.0}, 300, function() {
        //when done animating out, animate next in
        $previous.css({opacity:0.0})
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 400, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $previous.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

If I `console.log()` `$active` and `$previous`, I keep getting the same thing. Is there any way I can make the `$previous` variable actually be the previous image as before? I think `.prev()` now is making it go to the anchor link instead of the previous image, though I may be wrong.

To see a live version of this code, it can be viewed at http://engineercreativity.com/samples/daf. The site is not in English, though I don't think that should affect anything.

Thanks for your help!
Amit

Comment: The reason I use `jQuery()` rather than `$()` is because I have the lightbox plugin installed as well, which uses prototype.js, therefore I had to avoid the `$` conflict

Comment: Lastly, this slideshow is actually going `backwards` rather than forwards since Hebrew is read from right to left. I know, it's whack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use as a relative selector `<a>` tag: it may help

> ```
> jQuery('#slideshowImages a:first').addClass('active');
> ```
>
> jQuery('#slideshowImages
>   a:last').addClass('lastImg');
>
> var $active = jQuery('#slideshowImages
>   a.active');
>
> var $previous = $active.prev().length
>   ? $active.prev():
>   jQuery('#slideshowImages a.lastImg');
>
> ```
> $active.animate({opacity:0.0}, 300, function() {
>     //when done animating out, animate next in
>     $previous.css({opacity:0.0})
>         .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 400, function() {
>         $active.removeClass('active');
>         $previous.addClass('active');
> }); });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I ended up using a part of your solution. Unfortunately, changing the opacity of the anchor links won't do anything, so you have to modify it a little bit with `$active.find('img').animate(...)` and the same for `$previous...`. Marked correct for leading me towards the right path. Thanks